# Insert record if not exist without Unique key

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this code, but sometimes it's inserting me double records. I cannot set a unique key for field `user_subid`.

```php
$sql="SELECT `user_subid` FROM `clicks` WHERE `user_subid`='".$user_subid."'";
$query=mysql_query($sql);
if(mysql_num_rows($query)==0){
    $sqlIns="INSERT INTO `clicks` (`file_id`, `country`, `date`, `timeClick`, `user_subid`) VALUES ('".$fileid."', '".$country."', '".$date."', '".$timeClick."', '".$user_subid."')";
    if(mysql_query($sqlIns)==true){
        echo 1;
    }
    else { echo 0;}
}
```

I tried with:

```
INSERT INTO `clicks` (
`id` ,
`file_id` ,
`country` ,
`date` ,
`timeClick` ,
`user_subid`
)
VALUES (
NULL , '1500', 'Canada', '2014-05-24', '1400934475', '7c282b9227328778680d5826e01f6d'
) WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `clicks` WHERE `user_subid`='7c282b9227328778680d5826e01f6d');
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you looking for this ?

> INSERT ***IGNORE*** INTO clicks ( id , file_id , country , date , timeClick , user_subid ) 
>       VALUES ( NULL , '1500', 'Canada', '2014-05-24', '1400934475', '7c282b9227328778680d5826e01f6d' )

EDIT:

```
 INSERT INTO `clicks` (
  `id` ,
  `file_id` ,
  `country` ,
  `date` ,
  `timeClick` ,
  `user_subid`
 )
 SELECT `id` ,
`file_id` ,
`country` ,
`date` ,
`timeClick` ,
`user_subid`
FROM  
 (SELECT NULL id , '1500' `file_id` , 'Canada' `country` , '2014-05-24' `date` , '1400934475' `timeClick` , '7c282b9227328778680d5826e01f6d' `user_subid`) a 
LEFT JOIN `clicks` b ON 
  a.id = b.id AND a.`file_id` = b.`file_id` AND a.`user_subid` = b.`user_subid` 
WHERE b.`user_subid` IS NULL;
```

or with NOT EXIST

```
  INSERT INTO `clicks` (
  `id` ,
  `file_id` ,
  `country` ,
  `date` ,
  `timeClick` ,
  `user_subid`
 )
 SELECT `id` ,
`file_id` ,
`country` ,
`date` ,
`timeClick` ,
`user_subid`
FROM  
 (SELECT NULL id , '1500' `file_id` , 'Canada' `country` , '2014-05-24' `date` , '1400934475' `timeClick` , '7c282b9227328778680d5826e01f6d' `user_subid`) a
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 
   FROM `clicks` 
   WHERE `user_subid` = '7c282b9227328778680d5826e01f6d')
```

Comment: No, I tried with your code, but it's still inserting me.

Answer (score 1):

Is your SQL is working?

If you want update recode if recode is exist. Otherwise insert new recode. Just try UPSERT CODE. [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;
```

Comment: use your primary key. table should have primary key.

Answer (score 0):

have you try to change

```
$sql="SELECT `user_subid` FROM `clicks` WHERE `user_subid`='".$user_subid."'";
$query=mysql_query($sql);
if(mysql_num_rows($query) < 1){ // change == 0 to < 1
$sqlIns="INSERT INTO `clicks` (`file_id`, `country`, `date`, `timeClick`, `user_subid`)   VALUES ('".$fileid."', '".$country."', '".$date."', '".$timeClick."', '".$user_subid."')";
if(mysql_query($sqlIns)==true){
    echo 1;
}
   else { echo 0;}
}
```

Comment: I need to insert only if not exist. For unique clicks. But i Cannot set Unique Key.