# Insert if not exists, no unique key

Tags: mysql

I want the name column to be unique here.
Because other problem unique keys cannot be added, cannot use on duplicate key update.

I try use insert select, but not work.

```sql
INSERT INTO test2 (NAME, hotStatus)
SELECT 'A', 1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM test2 WHERE NAME = 'A' LIMIT 1);
```

table is:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `test2` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(10),
  `hotStatus` tinyint(1),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

```java
@Test
public void testInsert() throws InterruptedException {
    final int COUNT = 20;

    Thread[] ta = new Thread[COUNT];
    for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {
        int hotStatus = i % 2;
        ta[i] = new Thread(() -> getConn()
                .update("INSERT INTO test2 (NAME, hotStatus) " +
                        "SELECT 'A', ? WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM test2 WHERE NAME = 'A' LIMIT 1);", 
                        hotStatus));
    }
    for (Thread t : ta) {
        t.start();
    }
    for (Thread t : ta) {
        t.join();
    }
}
```

The table is empty before running the test.
After I run this test, there are a dozen more data in test2.

```
id  name hotStatus
3   A    1
4   A    0
5   A    0
6   A    0
7   A    1
```

I try select for update, but can't lock it.

```sql
select * from test2 where name = 'A' for update;
```

I see other question, but not got answer

- [mysql insert if not exist without unique key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22848075/mysql-insert-if-not-exist-without-unique-key)
- [Insert record if not exist without Unique key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23846106/insert-record-if-not-exist-without-unique-key)

Answer (score 0):

Cannot find any problem (except excess LIMIT in subquery).

```
INSERT INTO test2 (NAME, hotStatus)
SELECT @name, 1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 
                   FROM test2 
                   WHERE NAME = @name );
```

where `@name` variable is used for `name` value to be inserted (literal may be used like in a question).

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=cdf891ee6163d18552ddd00f6b744462)

Comment: No data in the initial table, I tested under high concurrency and most of the inserts were successful, resulting in close to twenty data with a name of 'A' in the end

Comment: @SpirytusRektyfikowany *resulting in close to twenty data with a name of 'A' in the end* Your explanation looks like `name` column MUST be unique. Please explain *Because other problem unique keys cannot be added* more detailed in your question - maybe you should solve that problem instead of this one?

Comment: Very realistic question, because we have to wait long for other departments